# How is atomic position expressed in QM?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, condensed-matter, nuclear-physics, molecular-dynamics, density-functional-theory

I am trying to understand how DFT works. I understand how to express the position of an atom or molecule in terms of the positions of the nuclei and electrons by setting up a Hamiltonian expressed in terms of these quantities. But the term 'atomic position' makes no sense for me, as the atom consists of a number of parts.

My questions: How is 'atomic position' calculated if the position of the nucleus and electrons are known? Conversely, can something mathematically precise be said about the position of the nucleus and electrons (such an expected value for example) if the atomic position is known?

Comment: Given the huge mass imbalance, the 'atomic' position is that of the nucleus, starting at least from the Born-Oppenheimer approximation. All electrons not considered in DFT are part of the nucleus.

Comment: @JonCuster Alright, thanks. And how do one get rid of the dependence of electron positions in the observables? Are the DFT observables simply expected values over all electron position space?

Comment: DFT is a full on quantum solution to the electron probability distribution functions. So, what do you mean by electron 'positions' with respect to DFT?

Comment: Suppose that $R \in \mathbb{R}^{3n}$ contains all nuclei positions and $r \in \mathbb{R}^{3k}$ contains all electron positions. Is it then true that in DFT, the energy as a function of atomic positions $E(R) = \int_{\text{all space}} \psi(R,r)^* \widehat{E} \psi(R,r) d^{3k} r$?

Comment: The electron 'positions' are wave functions.

Answer (score 0):

Position is expressed in QM via the position basis, $|x)$. When we are given a state $|u)$, then we have a wave function $u(x) := (x|u)$, and this expresses the state as a function of position.

However, this is not what the main body of the question is asking. A Hamiltonian for an atom or a molecule will depend on the details of the system in question. Typically, most introductory texts on QM set up the Schrodinger equation for the hydrogen atom, you might find it worth going over such an exposition.